# How to properly read the Shell Grammar?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, posix

How to correctly and precisely read the Shell Grammar hosted at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02, especially that is written after "*The grammar symbols*"? I'm not saying i can't get it at all, i understand it roughly, but i think there should be something like a "standard for standard" on how to read and write Shell Grammar properly..

Comment: Looks like yacc style BNF.

Comment: This is very useful, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With gratitude to *[Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9952196/shawn)*, it turned out that Shell Grammar uses the "yacc-style [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) syntax" which is described at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/yacc.html#tag_20_159_13 (or an easier to read version [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yacc.1p.html#EXTENDED_DESCRIPTION)).